# I tried to compile my code and got error `time display in class TIME does not name a type`

Tags: c++

I created a new class called `TIME` and tried to define a method (`time_display`) in another .cpp file. I added the header file 'time.h' where the class `TIME` was defined. I tried to compile this code, but got an error message `time display in class TIME does not name a type` in line 6.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "time.h"

class TIME::time_display() {
    // Program to print digital clock using graphics goes here
    return 0;
}
```

This is my header file. I changed the file name but it still produces the same error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

class TIME {
    int seconds, minutes, hours;
public:
    void time_display();
};
```

Comment: Please show us your header. Also `time.h` is potentially dangerous naming choice, there exists standard C header with the same name.

Comment: In fact, that's probably the problem.

Comment: I think it's okay as long as OP uses `""` in include. That `class` keyword looks more suspicious

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Oh yeah :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will check that out now.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I just tried out what you suggested. I still have the same problems. I tried changing the name of the header file and the .cpp file .

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  What do you think is wrong with the class definition.

Comment: @MOSESAMAECHI I don't think it's wrong. I wanted you to include it in the question, so that we can answer properly. The answer given below is most likely correct, but you can see it's guessing things (like return type of your function). On StackOverflow we expect [mcve] in the question - this lets us provide good quality answer to the actual problem (not the one we guess you have).

Answer (score 3):

I think your mixing up a couple of things here.

Your class declaration in `time.h` should be something like this:

```
class TIME {       
  public:             
    void time_display(); 
};
```

Your class method definition should be something like this. Let's call that file `TIME.cpp`.

```
#include "time.h"

void TIME::time_display() {
    // void function doesn't return anything
}
```

So now you may have three files: main.cpp, TIME.cpp and time.h. To compile it use this for example:

```
g++ TIME.cpp main.cpp -o time_display
```

To get an executable named `time_display`

Comment: I just added the header file to the question

Comment: please also put the filenames so I can reference them. Are you sure you have changed "class TIME::time_display()" to "void TIME::time_display()" ? If you have update your code in your question. Is the error still the same?