# This is my .h file. I changed the .h file name but it still produces the same error. 'time_display' in 'class TIME'

Tags: c++

/*This is my .h file. I changed the .h file name but it still produces the same error. 'time_display' in 'class TIME' does not name a type in line 6 of the cpp file*/

````
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
 class TIME {
  int seconds, minutes, hours;
 public:
    void time_display();
 };```

/*This is the cpp file. It keeps giving me the same error message in line 6*/
`#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "time_file.h"
class TIME::time_display(){
    //Program to print digital clock using graphics goes here
     
}`
````

Comment: So you showed your header, but said the cpp file is indicating an error, can you show the cpp file?

Comment: @Cory Kramer  I just added the cpp file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I tried to compile this code in the .cpp file and i got the error message"time display in class TIME does not name a type" in line 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62934968/i-tried-to-compile-this-code-in-the-cpp-file-and-i-got-the-error-messagetime-d)

Comment: You were already told how to fix this in your last question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say `class TIME::time_display()` you should say `void TIME::time_display()`.

basically when defining a member function you want the same signature thats in your header (in this case `void time_display()`) but with the `classname::` (in this case `TIME::`) in front of the function name.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. It just worked. Please if i may ask, why is the void included before the class `TIME` instead of before the method `time_display` in the .cpp file. If I had an int type should i do the same.

Comment: @MOSESAMAECHI the full name of the method to refer to when defining outside of the class is `TIME::time_display`. The `TIME::` is technically part of the name so thats why it goes after the return type, and this is the approach for any method being defined in the cpp so its the same even for different return types e.g. int

Comment: @MOSESAMAECHI no problem!